# Next sibling with class in CSS / SCSS

Tags: css, sass, less

I have a small list with the following classes

```
<ul>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="first--blue"></li>
<li class="first--blue"></li>
<li class="first--blue"></li>
<li class="first"></li>
<li class="first"></li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to change the class of the `<li class="first--blue"></li>`  to have a blue background, but I want to change it only to the first `"first--blue"` not the other ones

Comment: have you tried `.first + .first--blue`?

Comment: You could give it an id or another class. Why do those three list items need to have the same class, if they don't use the same CSS settings?

Comment: @Geshode the list is coming from an API, I can't change the classes or ids nor I can use JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.first--blue ~ .first--blue` to indicate the `first--blue` that is not the first one.

Just remember to set anything that defined in `.first--blue` to its initial state in `.first--blue ~ .first--blue`.

```css
li {
  height: 10px;
}

/* The first first--blue */
.first--blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Other first--blue */
.first--blue ~ .first--blue {
  background-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li class="first--blue"></li>
  <li class="first--blue"></li>
  <li class="first--blue"></li>
  <li class="first"></li>
  <li class="first"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only apply first child property to a certain tag, but not to a class. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/13788978) are detailed explaination on how to apply all class and then undo to achieve the first child class property answered previously.